# Is there a difference between explicitly putting the type into the diamond operator vs letting java figure it out?

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference between initialization via:

```
MyWrapper<String> wrapper = new MyWrapper<String>();
```

vs initialization via:

```
MyWrapper<String> wrapper = new MyWrapper<>();
```

Is there any reason why one would want to use the former over the latter?  I see a lot of the former; I'm not sure if it's just because that's what people are used to, or there's a reason you'd want to write it that way.

Comment: To be clear -- you are aware that `new MyWrapper<>()` is a new notation, not supported in earlier versions of Java?

Comment: They generate identical byte code

Comment: Use the latter when you know for certain that your code will run on java7 or higher, use the former if you don't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latter is only available since Java 7. That's why you often see the former. The latter is equivalent, and shorter.

Answer (score 4):

JDK 7 allows to not redefine this "redundant" diamond at initialization time.

It's just a shorter syntax.

With JDK <= JDK 6, the latter doesn't work, you have to use the former.

Answer (score 2):

It is largely because while Java 7 is the current version, a lot of code still uses Java 6, which does not support the latter form.

In essence, Java 7 compilers are better at infering generic types.

Comment: "Java 7 compilers are better at infering generic types" Inference is not necessary for the diamond operator.

Answer (score 0):

Before Java 7, the former was required. Now with [type inferencing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), the latter is preferred.

Comment: Type inference has always existed in generics.