# Whats the difference between List<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>(); and List<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java

Being just a beginner in JAVA, I am unable to understand the difference between the two. Both the codes were working perfectly in my Eclipse program.

Comment: There is no difference. The latter (aka the diamond operator) is only supported since Java 7.

Comment: Also you can read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346510/propper-initialization-of-an-arraylist and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033206/is-there-a-difference-between-explicitly-putting-the-type-into-the-diamond-opera
@T.J.Crowder Thanks for reminding the dupe.